# What is the most efficient way at extracting a string out of a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python function that outputs strings like THIS.

```
    if (X1079) { clearTimeout (X1079); X1079 = null; }
X781 ('<FORM name="X58" method="POST" action="http://us21.chatzy.com/56024939146241"><DIV style="display:none;"><INPUT type="hidden" name="X1" value="218"></DIV><DIV style="display:none;"><INPUT type="hidden" name="X579" value="1"></DIV><DIV style="display:none;"><INPUT type="hidden" name="X691" value="NTYwMjQ5MzkxNDYyNDEmNTYwMjQ5MzkxNDYyNDEmMCZYMTY4JjE0MjI1NTUxMDkmSllJR0lOVk0mYXl5JkZGRkZGRiYmMSYzJjEmdXdvb2RsZXM3Nzc2QGpvdXJyYXBpZGUuY29tJjd6c3AwJjE0MjI4MDM4NDMmJjAm"></DIV></FORM>');
```

Now, at the very end, is a string that is encoded in Base64

```
NTYwMjQ5MzkxNDYyNDEmNTYwMjQ5MzkxNDYyNDEmMCZYMTY4JjE0MjI1NTUxMDkmSllJR0lOVk0mYXl5JkZGRkZGRiYmMSYzJjEmdXdvb2RsZXM3Nzc2QGpvdXJyYXBpZGUuY29tJjd6c3AwJjE0MjI4MDM4NDMmJjAm
```

But I could not imagine any practical way to extract that very string every time, given that the first (longer) string changes *everytime* and can have varying contents and lengths, anyway, then that Base64 string is decoded into THIS.

```
56024939146241&56024939146241&0&X168&1422555109&JYIGINVM&ayy&FFFFFF&&1&3&1&uwoodles7776@jourrapide.com&7zsp0&1422803843&&0&
```

Now, we also see this part of the decoded string

```
JYIGINVM
```

That's what I need to get, it should be noted that the contents of all the strings above change every time, even in length too, all change but a few things like the ampersands and value's names in the first string. It should also be noted that the eight letters we want from the third string are always after the fifth ampersand.

I have tried almost too many times to do this, basing my code on research from the internet, but I have not been able to reach any consistent results, so, I came here to ask what the most favorable way to undertake the task be, if possible, some examples, too. Thank you in advance. :)

OTHER EXAMPLE OF THE FIRST STRING.

```
if (X1079) { clearTimeout (X1079); X1079 = null; }
X781 ('<FORM name="X58" method="POST" action="http://us23.chatzy.com/31039888252154"><DIV style="display:none;"><INPUT type="hidden" name="X1" value="218"></DIV><DIV style="display:none;"><INPUT type="hidden" name="X579" value="1"></DIV><DIV style="display:none;"><INPUT type="hidden" name="X691" value="MzEwMzk4ODgyNTIxNTQmMzEwMzk4ODgyNTIxNTQmMCZYMTY4JjE0MjI1NTY0MjcmVUZWS0VPUUEmYXl5JkZGRkZGRiYmMSYzJjEmdXdvb2RsZXM3Nzc2QGpvdXJyYXBpZGUuY29tJjd6c3AwJjE0MjI4MDM4NDMmJjAm"></DIV></FORM>');
```

Comment: I guess you need to define some more cases ? may be , to detect a pattern among all of them, That could be the only way out I think , not sure though , regular expression can help in that case

Comment: Have you tried the re module? It feels like the best solution here...

Comment: The actual string it outputs starts with that conditional expression? Or does it start with actual HTML, like `'<FORM` in your example?

Comment: @Oliver W. It starts just like the one I pasted, here is another example in the main question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a `re` way to do it:

```
import re
import base64

data = """
if (X1079) { clearTimeout (X1079); X1079 = null; }
X781 ('<FORM name="X58" method="POST" action="http://us23.chatzy.com/31039888252154"><DIV style="display:none;"><INPUT type="hidden" name="X1" value="218"></DIV><DIV style="display:none;"><INPUT type="hidden" name="X579" value="1"></DIV><DIV style="display:none;"><INPUT type="hidden" name="X691" value="MzEwMzk4ODgyNTIxNTQmMzEwMzk4ODgyNTIxNTQmMCZYMTY4JjE0MjI1NTY0MjcmVUZWS0VPUUEmYXl5JkZGRkZGRiYmMSYzJjEmdXdvb2RsZXM3Nzc2QGpvdXJyYXBpZGUuY29tJjd6c3AwJjE0MjI4MDM4NDMmJjAm"></DIV></FORM>');"""

# Find length of characters starting with value=" and over 50 chars long
base64str = re.search("value=\"(\w{50,})\"", data).group(1)

# Decode
s = base64.decodebytes(base64str.encode()).decode(errors="ignore")

# Find section after 5th &
out = re.search("(.+?&){5}(.+?)&", s).group(2)

print(out)
```

An alternative first `re.search` is:

```
# Find the pattern name="X691" value="<base64 stuff>"
base64str = re.search("name=\"X691\" value=\"(\w+)\"", data).group(1)
```

This might work better, depending on how much your input length varies by.

Outputs `JYIGINVM` for your first example and `UFVKEOQA` for your second example. However, depending on how much your input varies, you may need to add more intelligence.

Comment: Your previous version was better (don't filter by `name`, the length is slightly more useful).

Comment: @OliverW. OK, I thought the name version might be more reliable, but I'll add both.

Comment: That's just preventive, because according to OP, the format can change everywhere (doubtful) in which case the `name` attribute isn't fixed to `X691` (once again, doubtful, most likely it will be fixed). In your previous version you didn't make that assumption and just based it on length (however, even the length can vary: just filter for `value` and it should have letters in it too).

Comment: He said that `all change but a few things like the ampersands and value's names in the first string`. I think he meant the `name="X691"` bit?

Comment: Indeed X691 does not change, I am testing your solution now. :)

Comment: Your solution works, thank you so much! Hopefully one day I might understand the regular expression magic...

Comment: I don't think I fully understand them yet. And I've been told python regexes are simple compared to perl...